# Excel: Can offset use a named value?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I get the offset function to use the `myRange` value that was established earlier?

Specifcally, I have a value `myRange` that is (num of days in month + 3), so that the formula accounts for the number of days in a month and appears on the correct line. Later, I am trying to use the value of `myRange` in the offset function but when I hover over it, it returns:  `myRange = 0`.  When I go into the name manager, I can see `myRange` and it has a value (34 in this case) and it referes to a specific cell and is scoped for the workbook. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=numDays+3"
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "General"    
ActiveCell.Name = "myRange"
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
While ActiveCell.Value <> Empty
    ActiveCell.Offset(myRange, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaArray = "=SUM((WEEKDAY(startDate:endDate)=3)*(R[-32]C:R[-2]C<>""""))"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Wend
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ActiveCell.Offset([myRange], 0).Select
```